# How to use xcode project files into another xcode project within same workspace?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-workspace

i am creating new xcode workspace in which i have created 3 new projects(Common Project , Project A and Project B).

In which Common project will include common Controllers and classes which will be used into other two projects.

--So I have added One view controller in Common Project , and now how to use it into another two projects.

So far i've tried to Change build setting (Header Search Path) of Project A and added Path of Common Project there . but it is giving me linking error

Comment: post that linking error ,then we can tell about the what problem you are facing...

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: goto build phase and check is there any .m file is in red color...

Comment: You need not just set the path to public common headers, but also link a built static library.

Comment: @KishoreKumar there is not .m file in red color.
and all three projects are newly created xcode project . there is no external library

Comment: Anyone has any solution to this?